# Select query based on where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have purchase table that has fields purchase id,received ,itemid and some other fields.

The purchase order has multiple line items. When you create the purchase order for the first time the received field for each line item will be 0. As you receive item the line item received field changes to 1. I want to select only those records where received field for all line item are 0.For example

```
Pono   received  itemid
 100     0         1
 100     0         2
 100     1         3
 100     0         4    
 101     0         1
 101     0         5
 101     0         3

 101     0         6
```

Here the pono  100 has  4 line items .since the  itemid 3 has received =1 i want to exclude the pono 100 from select statement.
 I want to select only those pono 's where all the line items have received = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're after all details of all records where the PO number is 0 for all lines.  First generate a set of data having PONO with any received=1 and then select from your base set where it doesn't exist in your generated set.

```
SELECT PONO, Received, ItemID
FROM tableName T1
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM tablename T2 
                  WHERE received=1
                    and T1.PONO=T2.PONO)
```

or

```
SELECT PONO, Received, ItemID
FROM tableName T1
WHERE PONO not in (SELECT Distinct PONO 
                  FROM tablename T2 
                  WHERE received=1)
```

Or

```
    SELECT PONO, Received, ItemID
    FROM tableName T1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Distinct PONO 
                      FROM tablename 
                      WHERE received=1) T2
      on T1.PONO = T2.PONO
   where T2.PONO is null
```

Each has different performance depending on indexes and data statistics so they will all perform differently.

Comment: Thank You Very much for quick response.

Comment: Note that these queries will return duplicate rows.  I don't know if that is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

So, If I understand right, you are looking for selecting only those fields where total received is 0.

You need to perform grouping with having clause.

```
select Pono from <tablename> group by PONO having max(received)=0
```

Comment: However, I prefer `max()` over `sum()`.

Comment: Agreed. That will have lesser overhead than sum.

Comment: . . Really, they are about the same in terms of effort (unless the database is using a non-native numeric format).  I just think `max()` is clearer in terms of intention.

Comment: Well, in either case, question asker was looking for something else it seems... :-)

Answer (score 1):

`select Pono from <tablename> where received=0`

`select * from <tablename> where received=0`

You asked both for only the Pono and the entire record, these will do both of those requests respectively.

Comment: The above statement  select the pono  100. I want to exclude  pono =100 because it has one item with received = 1

Comment: That was definitely not clear by your original request. There are many ways to do it. Max, sum, not in sub query, etc.